# Laravel 4 arabic characters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-4, utf-8

I have a `laravel 4.2` project and I have a `utf8` fields in database, but the way the data is stored in this filed is like `Ø±Ø§` characters.

In any php file (other than laravel) after selecting the data from database those characters rendered in correct way after using (*SET NAMES '**utf8**'*).  I want to do same in laravel. (even if not a database solution)

Here is what i have tried:

1. make sure all files are `utf8`
2. make sure that in config files charset and collation are `utf8`
3. use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"` in config files

I also tried to use `Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');` but did not know how to use it in correct way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i have forgot to mention that i have used  iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $description); and it gives me some of the characters right and others as diamond shape .may someone suggest another encoding thatn iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is how i get it to work :

my problem was the opposite of what i thought .

all what i did is removing utf8 settings from database.php config file , and comment 
line $connection->prepare($names)->execute(); in  MysqlConnector.php file

and the right words shown
thanks for all  and if any one know a better solution please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use iconv.  Do not use utf8_encode.

You have Mojibake.

Were you expecting `را` instead of `Ø±Ø§`?  Is this the HEX that is in the table:  `D8B1D8A7`?

This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

If you need to **fix the data** it takes a "2-step ALTER", something like

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.

Comment: thanks for reply , first time to hear the concept "Mojibake" .i have removed   utf8 settings from database.php config file ,  which is used to set names as utf 8 in mysql connect  and the right words shown correctly.  i cannot alter my database cause it is used by android and ios developers and everything is correct with them . should i answer my question with what i get or there is something more professional ?

Comment: If you are satisfied that my answer solved your problem, click the checkmark to acknowledge that.  I assume that "the right words shown correctly" means that you are getting correct Arabic instead of gibberish.

Comment: thanks again for your answer .,but i changed the way i connect to database  and didnot alter the database as i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Set CHARACTER SET to utf8 and COLLATE to utf8_general_ci of your database, table, and column.

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name column_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: OUCH!  `CONVERT TO` and `MODIFY column` do two different things.  If you do both, I cringe to think what kind of mess you will end up with!